# getting error for "NA" values while reading file using read_csv() using tiddyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, na, data-wrangling, readr

I am trying to read a file in which a column generally contains a double but when the value is neutral it has "Calm" as its value. So when I read the file I am using `na = "Calm | calm"` and inside `col_types = cols()` I am parsing the column using `'9am wind speed (km/h)' = col_double()` below is my function for making tibbles.

```
generate_tibble <- function(filename) {
    temp_tibble <- read_csv(
            paste0("./data/", filename),
            na = c('calm',"Calm"),
            skip = 7,
            col_types = cols(
               'Date' = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
               'Evaporation (mm)' = col_double(),
               'Sunshine (hours)' = col_double(),
               '9am wind speed (km/h)' = col_double()
               )
            )
    }
```

after that, I read my first file like this: `main_df <- generate_tibble(file_names[1])` with which I am going to merge other files using the column names. So I run the loop using the following code.

```
for (i in file_names[2:length(file_names)]) {
  temp <- generate_tibble(i)
  main_df <- rbind(main_df, temp)
  print(paste("FINISHED PARSING:", i))
}
```

but when I run the loop I get errors like this:

[image: the error after the loop]

when I run `problems(main_df)` it show this message:
[image: message after running problems()]

what should I do to fix this issue? thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on what's showing up in `problems(main_df)` you could manually check what is in (for example) row 2 column 5. Looks like it's "" which is not a double. You could add that to `na = `.

Comment: Side note, your loop isn't allocating memory efficiently. https://evodify.com/r-loops-are-slow/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to Type set and process inside of the read_csv you can try doing the formatting after the file has been read. Here is a tidy version of your function

```
generate_tibble <- function(filename) {

 temp_tibble <- read_csv(file.path(".","data","filename")) %>%
                mutate('Date' = col_date(format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
               'Evaporation (mm)' = col_double(),
               'Sunshine (hours)' = col_double(),
               '9am wind speed (km/h)' = col_double())

}
```

All string values should be turned into NA when you force the column to be numeric. So you should not need to specify "Calm". The `file.path()` function is made for file paths so that your code can be used by both Linux and Windows users.

After that I recommend using an `lapply()` function instead of a loop and binding the product of the lapply using `data.table::rbindlist()`

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family?utm_source=adwords_ppc&utm_campaignid=12492439679&utm_adgroupid=122563408041&utm_device=c&utm_keyword=apply%20family%20r&utm_matchtype=b&utm_network=g&utm_adpostion=&utm_creative=504158803141&utm_targetid=aud-522010995285:kwd-614516587376&utm_loc_interest_ms=&utm_loc_physical_ms=9028709&gclid=Cj0KCQjw18WKBhCUARIsAFiW7JzR0Avzz054y2tx2b1Sx7hZOEGHMRxfNdmgodVnzh9fqNUyg5JsAz4aAvvyEALw_wcB#codelapplycode